# 'date -d' not working in my ksh shell

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I need to calculate difference between two dates and result be in HH:SS format.

But the problem is, my date/shell does not support '-d' flag. Most of the articles are suggesting '-d' option only.

```
input date format = '07-Apr-2017 02:19:20'
```

This is equivalent to

```
date +"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

When I used date -d, I am getting error like "Invalid character in date/time specification"

Comment: `date` is actually provided by your OS, not by the shell itself. So it doesn't matter if you're using bash, ksh, ash, etc. (or even no shell at all -- you can invoke `/usr/bin/date`, like any other executable, directly from C), but which version of `date` your OS vendor provides.

Comment: ...so, it'd be helpful to know (1) your actual operating system, and (2) which tools you *do* have. (`perl` actually has some very comprehensive date libraries available; Python has some good tooling out-of-the-box as well).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about shell vs Os in this context. (1) When i checked with 'uname -a' it showed me 'AIX' server. (2) I would like to do calculation with in same shell script instead of calling another perl/python just for calculation. Is it possible with in shell script?

Comment: The `date` command provided by AIX is *extremely* rudimentary. It may be `perl`, `python` or `awk`, but you'll need to run something else.

Comment: (and the specific `awk` matters -- if you have `gawk` installed, it has a quite decent set of date management functions).

Comment: (btw, it'd be helpful to know not just that it's AIX, but which version thereof).

Comment: Its version 7, release 1

Comment: which version of ksh are you using?

Comment: $SHELL --version. This gave me like "sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2009-05-01"

Comment: does my answer work for you at last?

Comment: Nope. I had to use perl finally as I could not figure out exact issue with the shell. However thanks for pointing out the my login shell issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet `ksh93t+` should support `printf '%(fmt)T'`.

```
[STEP 101] $ echo ${.sh.version}
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
[STEP 102] $ date -d '07-Apr-2017 02:19:20' +%s  # GNU date
1491502760
[STEP 103] $ printf '%(%s)T\n' '07-Apr-2017 02:19:20'
1491502760
[STEP 104] $
```

Comment: It is working from command line not from shell script, just giving output like ()T from shell script. Should I do something for to work in shell script?

Comment: what does the 1st line of your shell script look like? and how did you run your script? mind sharing your script so others can help take a look? any error when you run the script?

Comment: `#! usr/bin/ksh` This is the first line..I am running it like `sh test.ksh`

Comment: sh is not always ksh so you better use `ksh test.ksh`

Comment: Tried `ksh tesh.ksh`. Still not getting desired output..Am I missing anything here?

Comment: any error message? what's the output of `ksh --version`?

Comment: its not throwing any error..simply showing `()T` in the output. `ksh --version` gave me an error..but `ksh93 --version` returned `sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2009-05-01`

Comment: sounds like in your system `ksh` is actually `ksh88` (it's very old!) so you should use `ksh93` then.

Comment: But `echo $SHELL` returns `/usr/bin/ksh93` not `ksh88`

Comment: that may be because your *login shell* is set to `ksh93`.